# Vector shape is different than actual path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, shapes

I'm totally perplexed by this. The vector path is at a different location and of a different size than the actual shape seen. I'm using CS6. I got this file from a client.

[image: Does this make any sense!?!?]

Under normal circumstances, I could proceed as is. In this case, I'm uniting the 4 shapes and then setting it up for digital gold foil stamping. See what happens when I unite paths:

[image: unite paths!?!?]

Comment: PS: Reset bounding box did nothing.

Comment: Looks like an envelope warp or something. Sort of impossible to figure out with out the file to examine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your *Layers* panel I can see that the 3 groups and the selected vector path has some kind of *Appearance* effect applied to it. This can be seen by the "filled circles" in the right side of the *Layers* panel.

You can try to select everything (or one object at a time) and do *Object > Expand Appearance* to clean up the drawing.

That way the applied effects are "baked" into the path and are no longer editable.

Here is an example. Before expanding:

[image]

After expanding:

[image]